# Writing a method that computes compunded interest

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to write a method that computes compounded interest. This is the error message I keep getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '.'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
    at Balance.main(Balance.java:5)
```

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated. (The `System.out.printf("%.2\n", balance(1000.0, .05, 8.5));` is required by the homework)

```
public class Balance {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.printf("%.2\n", balance(1000.0, .05, 8.5));
}

public static double balance(double initialBalance, double interestRate,
        double years) {

    double compoundedInterest = initialBalance * Math.pow(1 + interestRate,        years);
    return compoundedInterest;
}
}
```

Comment: Arg. I was staring at that for so long. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `f` for floating format. Try `System.out.printf("%.2f\n",balance(1000.0, .05, 8.5));`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention the `f` to specify the float format there.

```
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", balance(1000.0, .05, 8.5)); // .2f is the proper syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what u have written

```
   System.out.printf("%.2\n", balance(1000.0, .05, 8.5));
```

i think  u missed f while writting %.2f

```
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", balance(1000.0, .05, 8.5));
```